# How to Merge/Join 2 DataFrames with multiple Index (python)

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, merge

Im new with the DataFrames and I try to merge 2 dataframes to try to "predict" the impact of weather in the host
The problem is that after this operation, the length is always 0

DataFrames:

```
clima_mod_15m.dtypes

date           datetime64[ns]
CP                       int64
max_temp               float64
min_temp               float64
avg_temp               float64
max_preci              float64
min_preci              float64
avg_preci              float64
max_wind               float64
min_wind               float64
avg_wind               float64
max_humidity           float64
min_humidity           float64
avg_humidity           float64

--------------------------------------------------
nodos_mod.dtypes

date                                 datetime64[ns]
CP                                             int64
cell                                         object
CELL_AVAILABILITY_EXCLUDING_HALTED           float64
```

Content of both dataframes. date and CP are the index on both

```
clima_mod_15m.head()

date    
CP   max_temp   min_temp    avg_temp    max_preci   min_preci   avg_preci   max_wind    min_wind    avg_wind    max_humidity    min_humidity    avg_humidity
                                                
2022-04-06 00:00:00 
15001   17.3    2.1 8.991667    0.0 0.0 0.0 2.3 0.2 1.1125  95.2    46.8    75.604167
15002   17.3    2.1 8.991667    0.0 0.0 0.0 2.3 0.2 1.1125  95.2    46.8    75.604167
15003   17.3    2.1 8.991667    0.0 0.0 0.0 2.3 0.2 1.1125  95.2    46.8    75.604167
15004   17.3    2.1 8.991667    0.0 0.0 0.0 2.3 0.2 1.1125  95.2    46.8    75.604167
15005   17.3    2.1 8.991667    0.0 0.0 0.0 2.3 0.2 1.1125  95.2    46.8    75.604167
... 
--------------------------------------------------
nodos_mod.head()    

date    
CP   cell   CELL_AVAILABILITY_EXCLUDING_HALTED
        
2022-03-19 14:30:00 
41920   ANDX0372F2A 0.0
41920   ANDX0372B1A 0.0
41920   ANDX0372B2A 0.0
41920   ANDX0372B3A 0.0
41920   ANDX0372F1A 0.0
...
```

When I execute

```
test = pd.merge(nodos_mod,clima_mod_15m,on=['fecha','CP'])
print(len(test))

out >> 0
```

The result is 0
What is happending here? What's wrong?

My expected result is join to the DataFrame nodos_mod the weather for the same date and CP (ZIP CODE)
similar to:

```
date   CP   cell   CELL_AVAILABILITY_EXCLUDING_HALTED   max_temp   min_temp 
  avg_temp
2022-03-19 14:30:00   41920   ANDX0372F2A   0.0   17.3   2.1   8.991667
```

Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should work, are you sure there are values in clima_mod_15m that are also in nodos_mod? In your example I cannot tell...

Comment: print(len(clima_mod_15m)) >> 7360

print(len(nodos_mod)) >> 1531200

Is necessary the same number of row for that operation?

Comment: As you said Paul, the problem was the dates. After update dates, the merge function correctly. I obtain around 3484 rows